# How to check the information of current installed video drivers?

Tags: xorg

My CPU usage is high when I do trivial things such as scrolling through a PDF file. So I think my video driver is not properly installed.

I want to confirm that by checking the information of my currently installed video driver, such as if there's a driver installed and what version it is. Then I could decide whether to install a new one if it is not up to date.

On Windows, I could use the device manager, how to do that on Ubuntu Linux? I don't expect a GUI solution for this. Command line will be just good enough.

Comment: Also see [How can I find what video driver is in use on my system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In Linux, there is two parts for the video driver, the kernel part and the X server part.

1. Let's identify your hardware first. By typing `lspci | grep VGA` in a terminal, you should see a line with you graphic card description (even if not configured at all).
2. Let's check the correct kernel driver is loaded `find /dev -group video`.
3. Let's check the correct X driver is loaded `glxinfo | grep -i vendor`.

If you want more help, I would like the result of following commands: (**Remember, never trust command line that people ask you to execute without knowing what it does.**)

```
lspci | grep VGA
lsmod | grep "kms\|drm"
find /dev -group video
cat /proc/cmdline
find /etc/modprobe.d/
cat /etc/modprobe.d/*kms*
ls /etc/X11/xorg.conf
glxinfo | grep -i "vendor\|rendering"
grep LoadModule /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Comment: Is this tow part thing the linux video driver model?

Comment: If you copy-paste the last 4 lines in a terminal and add the result at the end of your question (edit), it will be easier to answer your question. But *remember not to execute untrusted commands*. Perhaps some stackoverflow trusted users could proof read them and acknowledge in comments.

Comment: If the `glxinfo` command is not available, run `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`.

Comment: `grep VGA` will not always show all the devices.

Comment: Thanks for reminding people to not blindly execute commands they find online.

Answer (score 56):

The easiest way is to run

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
```

Example:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
```

This command will show all video PCI devices and kernel modules installed and in use.

Only `VGA` is not good enough, because Nvidia mobile adapters are shown as `3D` and some AMD adapters are shown as `Display`.

Comment: Thanks! I run command, it showed two controllers as in your example. Now how to find out what driver does what?

Comment: @Martian2020 It is unclear what you are asking. You see all drivers and which is used. You can ask a new question if you are more specific.

Comment: I meant what driver controls display output at the moment. I've understood `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"` could be used for that.

Answer (score 22):

I use this command to see what Xorg is currently using:

```
egrep -i " connected|card detect|primary dev|Setting driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Comment: Xorg.0.log is located in ${HOME}/.local/share in newer versions of Ubuntu

Comment: `${HOME}/.local/share/xorg` for me (20.04)

Answer (score 8):

Here is an easier solution, using GUI instead of command line.
on the Ubuntu desktop, choose:

**System Settings** > **Software and updates** (in the bottom) -> **Other drivers** (the right most tab).

This is a list of your video driver's information.
[image: my video driver's information]

Answer (score 5):

For nvidia drivers at least, I usually use the following command in the terminal:

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

Which will output something similar to the following:

```
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  346.96  Sun Aug 23 22:29:21 PDT 2015
```

Comment: It says, `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

I'm running a 64bit Ubuntu 10.04 here. Here's what I found out:

*lspci* will give you a list of found devices. Usually the video card is listed as "VGA controller" or somesuch, on my system it says:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G92 [GeForce 9800 GTX] (rev a2)
```

If you meant X.org's video driver, see */etc/X11/xorg.conf* and look for Driver in Section "Device" (there might be multiple):

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GTX/9800 GTX+"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9800 GTX/9800 GTX+"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection
```

If you need to find out the specific location of driver-file and version X.org's using, try  *cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log* and look for line which says something like **LoadModule "'Driver in the Device-section of xorg.conf'**, in my case:

```
(II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
(II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
(II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  195.36.24  Thu Apr 22 19:18:54 PDT 2010
(II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
(II) Primary Device is: PCI 01@00:00:0
```

Comment: This answer only applies to older distros. The newer versions appear to have moved away from xorg.conf

Comment: I'm on 12.04 and xorg.conf doesn't seem to exist, only xorg.conf.failsafe and xorg.conf.backup.

Comment: X.org auto-probes everything these days so there is no xorg.conf configuration file (unless you've explicitly made one).
*However the part about **inspecting the X server log** is still perfectly valid:
`less /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

Answer (score 2):

This should work with any unix-like operating system.

**First to list all PCI devices, run:**

> lspci -nn

`-nn` flag tells `lspci` to show PCI vendor and device codes as both numbers and names.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS400 Host Bridge [1002:5a33] (rev 01)
00:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS4xx PCI Express Port [ext gfx] [1002:5a34]
00:11.0 IDE interface [0101]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB400 Serial ATA Controller [1002:437a] (rev 80)
00:12.0 IDE interface [0101]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 Serial ATA Controller [1002:4379] (rev 80)
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB Host Controller [1002:4375] (rev 80)
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 USB2 Host Controller [1002:4373] (rev 80)
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 SMBus Controller [1002:4372] (rev 81)
00:14.1 IDE interface [0101]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 IDE Controller [1002:4376] (rev 80)
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller [1002:437b] (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] IXP SB4x0 PCI-PCI Bridge [1002:4371] (rev 80)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] [10de:0640] (rev a1)
02:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
```

Here in my case it is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] [10de:0640] (rev a1)
```

**Finally run**

```
sudo lspci -vvv -d 10de:0640
```

`sudo` and `-vvv` make it more verbose and helps display everything that it is able to parse. `-d` is for device in the format `[<vendor>]:[<device>]`

The final command will list out all the possible capabilities and the kernel driver in use.

Comment: `-k` is more useful that `-nn` in this case.