# How do i check if the Graphic drivers are installed correclty

Tags: ati

I have followed the following link :-

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-install-ati-amd-catalyst-122.html

to install the amd graphic drivers on my HP laptop. Just wanted to confirm if they are installed correctly.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: Run `lspci`, the device named VGA controller would be the device. Similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/28033/how-to-check-the-information-of-current-installed-video-drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run konsole or other terminal app, type "glxinfo" (without quotes) and press enter.
Scroll to the top of the output and find "client glx vendor string:" if there is no mesa or SGI, you have won.
Or... 
just reboot and run Catalyst control panel.

Comment: the command glxinfo isn't there; does this reflect incorrect installation?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wiki for the AMD Linux Driver verifying page](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Verifying)

Run this command in terminal

```
 fglrxinfo
```

for example it will show something like

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Radeon X1600 Series
OpenGL version string: 2.1.7415 Release
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo lshw -c video` and check for **"driver="**