# Can someone explain what this all means please?

Tags: drivers

I followed these instructions in a large (but now dead) thread in order to ascertain my video card and driver info seen below:

> In Linux, there is two parts for the video driver, the kernel part and the X server part.
>
> 1. Let's identify your hardware first. By typing `lspci | grep VGA` in a terminal, you should see a line with you graphic card description (even if not configured at all).
> 2. Let's check the correct kernel driver is loaded `find /dev -group video`.
> 3. Let's check the correct X driver is loaded `glxinfo | grep -i vendor`.

So when I type `lspci | grep VGA` I get a list of my PCI devices, which is just my video card:

```
Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290]
```

And when I type `find /dev -group video` I get a bunch of gobldygook
that I don't understand:

```
/dev/fb0
/dev/dri/card0
/dev/dri/renderD128
/dev/dri/controlD64
```

And when I type `glxinfo | grep -i vendor` I also get a bunch of nonsensical stuff (to me):

```
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
```

Can someone tell me if this machine has drivers or not? and if not can they please link to me the correct drivers?

Also I used the GUI to see if I have drivers and in all honesty its all just nonsense to me. [Here's a screenshot of my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cR8l.png)

Comment: This is the thread, right? [How to check the information of current installed video drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/q/28033/301745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me if this machine has drivers or not?

Your screenshot clearly states you are using the open source driver (the name for that is `xserver-xorg-video-ati`. That is a wrapper though and connects to one of these:

```
xserver-xorg-video-mach64    
xserver-xorg-video-r128   
xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

The ati wrapper autodetects if you have a Radeon, Rage 128, or Mach64 or earlier chip and loads the radeon, r128, or mach64 xorg video driver corresponding to your card).

> and if not can they please link to me the correct drivers?

All should be fine unless you want some more extra. The normal, open source version often lacks that little bit extra as it is a one-fits-all type of thing.

Besides the one currently active you can also opt for 2 versions from AMD itself from the screenshot you posted (proprietary, so owned by AMD) called `fglrx` and `fglrx-updates`. Sometimes it is worth installing this one as it often also comes with some tool where you can tweak the video card. Then again a general rule is: if it is not broken don't try to fix it; so if what is installed now works and you do not feel like you miss out on anything keep the open source driver.

By the way: if you had no driver for your videocard I doubt your system would even boot and it would crash as soon as anything videocard driver related was going to be shown; I assume that would be the purple greeting screen with the 3 dots.

Then there is also the official [Radeon](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) how to. You have an R9 290 so do note this bit of information:

> Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer: for some most recent graphics cards (R9 285, R9 380/380X, R9 M395X, R9 Nano/Fury/FuryX, RX 460/470/480, RX 550/560/570/580...) and APUs (Carrizo, Stoney), the open-source [AMDGPU](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMDGPU-Driver) driver is enabled by default. For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS AMDGPU-Pro hybrid driver is also available to download [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx) (please read the release notes for known problems and limitations).

It is about 16.04 and, as it is newer, 18.04 will have even better support.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Really! I only downloaded 14.04 because apparently that was the most current version supported by the flgrx drivers found on AMD's site, if I use a wrapper will I be able to get my 290 working on a newer version you think? Also whats the deal with having 2 different drivers? could you please explain what the difference between xorg and the kernel drivers are?

Comment: That wrapper is installed automatically on 16.04 and 18.04. I would have started with 18.04 if I was you and not 14.04. No harm in booting up a live session and to check 18.04 out before committing