# Add asymmetrical margin on LCD display?

Tags: display, screen, display-resolution, xrandr

My old laptop display is starting to break, and I have many dead pixels and other physical issues on the left side of the screen only. Of course I should get a new monitor (or ideally a new laptop), but as a workaround I'd like to configure the display to show a smaller screen size with a blank margin on the left where the broken area is.

It should look approximately like this:

```
+---+-----------------+--
| b |                 |
| l |    remaining    | 6
| a |     screen      | 0
| n |      area       | 0
| k |    (904x600)    |
+---+-----------------+--
|120|   -   904   -   |
|    -   1024    -    |
```

I've managed to use `cvt` to generate a 904x600 modeline, and I can add that mode to the display using `xrandr`, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to position the smaller screen on the right side of my full display. It seems like the `--pos` flag should work for this, but `xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 904x600_60.00 --pos 120x0` isn't working (the screen shows up centered in the display, with equal margins on left and right).

Any tips on how to get this to work? I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, in case it makes a difference. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Please add to the question info about the driver you are using. (Such advanced options depends on the used driver). `glxinfo | grep -e OpenGL -e glx` or see https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system/23240#23240

Comment: Have you figured this out? I have a very similar issue and the --pos flag is also not working for me. I'm on 18.04

Comment: @StaringFrog Unfortunately I never did figure this out. I replaced the laptop :-P Good luck to you though!

Answer (score 0):

### Using NVidia Driver

I put this here for who uses NVidia proprietary driver. So if it is not the case, please add to the question the driver you are using. (Such advanced options depends on the used driver)

1. Run `sudo nvidia-settings`
2. X Server Display Configuration tab → Set monitor from 'Selection:' → Advanced
3. BTW, This option is called *Under Scan*. Here an example for my monitor with 1280x800 original resolution. I removed 120 from left and 75 from bottom to keep same ratio.

   ```
   ViewPortIn: 1160x725
   ViewPortOut: 1160x725+120+0
   Panning: 1160x725
   ```
4. Apply

Note: You can save as the following screenshot to confirm it's size 1160x725

[image]

Margin can be seen here:

[image]