# XRandR to downsize and left-shift display output? (Underscan)

Tags: display, screen, xrandr

My old laptop has a crack on literally the right side of the screen, which luckily doesn't destroy the whole screen, but makes a small strip unusable.

[image: Laptop screen]

This is pretty frustrating, because you often cannot read menus and texts on this part of the screen. So I thought about downsizing the screen and position it to the left, from which the first is easily doable, but I don't know how to do the second.
At the moment, I am using `xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1200x768_60.0`, which scales down the screen, but positions it in center. I could of course make the x axis even smaller, but then I would also loose a strip on the left side, which is not what I want.

Side note: Using `--scale 0.88x1.0` makes it exactly the size I want, but well, it is scaled, and therefore looks horrible…

#### Device:

- Compaq 615 with Lubuntu 15.04
- AMD Graphics, Mesa driver

`glxinfo | grep -e OpenGL -e glx`:

```
max@aurora:~$ glxinfo | grep -e OpenGL -e glx
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.5.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

[This one](https://askubuntu.com/a/434974/164198) could be a duplicate, but it only provides an answer for NVidia drivers.