# What graphic card i use & how to switch between my cards?

Tags: xubuntu

I have ASUS X550CC-XX209 with installed xubuntu. My question is how do i know what gpu i use, intel or nvidia.And if i use intel, how to switch to nvidia card.I'm new linux user, so please don't use difficult terms.Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: To check https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system, to install NVidia see https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 0):

Following command gives you graphics detais.

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

The output will be like

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G41 x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 9.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
```

The second line gives you your driver's name.
You may also try

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL | grep renderer
```

Which will give only driver's name.

Comment: Sorry, but on xubuntu i don't have Dash

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the question properly.

Comment: Okay, i use intel card, now how to switch to nvidia?