# How can I get old video drivers back?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, video

No matter what I watch on hulu, or when I watch it, I see annoying flickering.

It doesn't happen on youtube, southparkstudios, or various other websites with videos that I have used since since updating to 12.04.

More details:
 I put a few different Ubuntu versions on my old Windows laptop. For Ubuntu 10.10 I had to install a couple of proprietary software drivers, including I think some video drivers.

But this new install (12.04) never asked me if I wanted to install those. And the command `jockey-text -l` run from terminal which is supposed to tell me about proprietary drivers doesn't list any video drivers.

Why didn't it ask me if I wanted the drivers again, as that seems the likely issue. What can I do to get the drivers myself? Why does anything work if there are no drivers?

On a side note I've noticed if I deliberately tax the cpu on my computer, hulu plays a little more smoothly. It seems to lag and only play fewer frames per second. It's as if it is skipping over the frames that were previously glitching out or something.

Update: I just discovered that using a pop out window makes the videos play perfectly. So I guess maybe this is a problem with their web page and not an Ubuntu problem. But I'm still curious about the drivers not being there. In windows there was some place I could go look at all the drivers, isn't there some kind of analogous place in ubuntu?

Comment: Some related info at http://askubuntu.com/a/23240 .