# How to check whether Ubuntu uses my graphics card?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have a n HP laptop with a fresh Ubuntu installed. How do I check whether it uses the nVIDIA graphics built in my laptop?

Comment: Have you checked this?http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system

Answer (score 0):

Run terminal and fire up

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

You will see a line describing your video card adapter. 
And run

```
man lspci
```

to see the manual on utility, it might help you alot in the future