# When watching videos in VLC on Ubuntu 14.10, it flickers

Tags: nvidia, graphics, vlc, 14.10

I have Ubuntu 14.10. When watching videos full screen with VLC the video flickers. Only on full screen. And it's not happening on other players (the default player and smplayer). How to fix this?

I have Nvidia graphics.

Comment: Use this thread to post your video driver type: http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system

Comment: Could you be more specific about your graphics card? What model, is it desktop or laptop?

Comment: @Serpens its a desktop and the card is Nvidia Gt640

Comment: Try to change VLC output method: Tools > Preferences > Video > Output

Comment: @Sneetsher What's the best?

Comment: @EApubs, it depends. The best is to try

Comment: I have an Nvidia card ... on ubuntu 16.04 after trying several nvidia driver releases I finally discovered the only flicker free one is  the open source Nouveau driver ... I switched between them using Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers ... although Nvidia drivers have worked flawlessly for previous installs ... only vlc flickered other apps were happy with Nvidia drivers

Comment: Do you have drivers pre-installed ?

Comment: Are you using the proprietary Nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. Changing hardware-accelerated decoding helped. 
Go to *Tools > Preferences > Input/Codecs*. 
Try different options in **hardware-accelerated decoding**. 
I first tried to disable it and it stopped flickering right away. 
However I noticed the video got frozen really quick (not that noticeable) couple times, so, the next option I tried worked perfectly: **VA-API video decoder via DRM**.

PS: to be sure that changes take effect, I restarted the player after saving the changed option

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue like you. You should use the latest nvidia driver

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc nvidia-* && sudo apt-get install nvidia-381 vlc
```

Comment: I guess you may want to reinstall vlc after those commands.