# Unity Launcher Crashes Computer When I have 2 instances of same program

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, dell, icons

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell XPS 13 laptop straight from Dell. They installed Ubuntu.

I have a problem whenever I have multiple windows of the same application open. Say I have 2 terminal windows or 2 sublimes. There will be 2 little tic marks to the left of the icon for the application on the launcher bar.

The first I click the icon the application surfaces. The second time I click it, the entire machine locks up and then reboots after a good 15 seconds of unresponsiveness.

I've tried googling this but I must not be using the right language. Any assistance with this would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, welcome to askubuntu :) Can you share your information on the graphics card and drivers you have? This question gives some brief information on how to get the information about the drivers: http://askubuntu.com/a/23240/16981

Comment: With the current information, all I can suggest is to look at the log files. Some have timestamps - see what happened at the time of crash. `less` (`man less`) is a tool that I use to examine `/var/log/Xorg.0.log /var/log/lightdm/{lightdm.log,x-0-greeter.log,x-0.log,x-1-greeter.log,x-1.log,x-2-greeter.log,x-2.log} $HOME/.xsession-errors` to begin. Please do NOT post entire, unexamined (by you) log files to AskUbuntu. Just show us the part(s) that indicate problems.

Comment: I will try to supply all those things. Probably tomorrow, Tuesday. In class and my final project is due Friday. Thanks in advance for those who are trying.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I solved it by :

1. Open Unity Tweak Tool
2. Press **General**
3. **Restore Default**

I really don't know what causes the problem
but that is what I did and somehow it worked well
for me.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solved the issue for me after restarting Unity. I think it has to do with a Window Spread setting, but I unfortunately didn't record what I had before restoring defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it, go on Unity Tweak and following steps, Windows Manager, Windows Spread, set checkbox, icons on preview.