# Radeon HD 7730 Active or Not

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have graphics card Radeon HD 7730, I have intel  i5 processor running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
Output of `fglrxinfo` follows:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2
```

Output of `lshw -c video` gives me:

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:c1000000-c13fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system) has an answer `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`
for its output it gives:

```
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

In my additional driver tab I see 3 drivers:

1. Using X.ord Xserver -AMD? ATI dispaly driver wrapper from `xserver-xorg-video-ati` (open source, tested)
2. Using Video driver from AMD graphics accelerators from `fglrx-updates` (proprietary)
3. Using Video driver for AMD graphics accelerators from `flgerx` (proprietary)

*The 3rd one is selected.*

The response of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'` is

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0572
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Chelsea LP [Radeon HD 7730M] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
```

---

Questions:

- I want to understand if my AMD card is served as graphics driver or i915?
- If not how can I make it happen?

Comment: @Zacharee1 can you please check it again

Comment: Did you reboot after selecting the driver?

Comment: `WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.` – Did you try that? The definitive resource to determine the graphics adapter/driver in use is always `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `fglrx` driver with dual graphics, you can check which adapter is in use In Catalyst Control Center, or by using a terminal command:

```
sudo aticonfig --pxl
```

Comment: It shows this message after this command 
`aticonfig: No supported adapters detected`

Comment: I want my graphics to be served from my graphics card  `Radeon HD 7730` .

Comment: Is Secure Boot disabled? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: can you please check now