# Minecraft Crashing

Tags: 12.04, java, crash, minecraft

**So i'm using ubuntu on a Chromebook, when i tried playing minecraft there was crashes i'm not so sure how to fix this problem please help :(** :

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Hey, that tickles! Hehehe!

Time: 9/4/16 6:44 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7f15fc635d00 serial: 30 error: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation) request_code: 153 minor_code: 14
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:320)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:828)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:320)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.<init>(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:828)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.10
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.10.18
    Java Version: 1.7.0_111, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 62884640 bytes (59 MB) / 165298176 bytes (157 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: install a GPU driver

Answer (score 0):

Install a GPU driver.

```
No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
```

means that you either have no xserver running (no window created for minecraft) or just missing video card driver.

Comment: How do i install a GPU driver? i'm pretty new and nooby to these type of things

Comment: do some "google-ing". What kind of GPU you have? [helpful link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system)

Comment: Well, i have a yoga 11e Chromebook Thinkpad