# After upgrading to ubuntu 16.04LTS my desktop will not recognize my msi R5450 graphics card.

Tags: graphics, gpu-driver

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04LTS my desktop will not recognize my msi R5450 graphics card.  I used sudo ubuntu-drivers devices to search and it only shows my processor as being the graphics provider. Did I miss something on the install?

Comment: Your card has an ATI Radeon HD 5450 and that's what matters, not the brand. If you have video your graphics card IS recognized. With 16.04 you don't have AMD Graphics proprietary drivers but it changes nothing considering your card is considered legacy by AMD and since a long time ago you don't have proprietary drivers available. You card works with the default open-source *radeon* driver, that's all, nothing else to install.

Comment: As @CelticWarrior referenced your video card is from 2011. Can you tell us if you actually have a problem with your system that needs to be fixed? Simply trying to find a driver that hasn't been written isn't a question.

Comment: My question mentioned nothing about "finding drivers".  I guess I should have explained that videos do not load and start quickly. I've had no lag time in the past, but I do now. Under setting for my computer this is what appears for graphics, Gallium 0.4 on AMD CEDAR (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0) I'm sorry if I'm not very technical, that is why I'm here, to ask questions, and learn.

Comment: Have you checked here to see if the driver is loaded:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system