# Installed GParted but it's not opening

Tags: partitioning, gnome, gparted, 16.10

I tried to open GParted after installing it, as it was not preinstalled in Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, but it just asked for root password but didn't open.

Then I tried to open from terminal and it showed this

```
jp@JP-PC:~$ sudo gparted
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/-.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/home.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-121.mount → /dev/null.
Created symlink /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount → /dev/null.
No protocol specified

(gpartedbin:3426): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
Removed /run/systemd/system/-.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/home.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/run-user-121.mount.
Removed /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount.
jp@JP-PC:~$
```

But it didn't start.
I also tried restarting computer.
Can anyone tell what's the problem with it.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your system architecture and what version of gparted did you install?

Comment: Did you install gparted from the gparted web site, or from the Ubuntu repositories? The correct answer is the latter.

Comment: could be an issue with xorg/wayland... make sure you have the correct graphics driver installed and nothing extra...

Comment: I have 32 bit version Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 and I installled GParted from software centre.

Comment: @Ridderhoff how do I check for correct graphic driver?

Comment: @JyotPrakashVerma http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system

Comment: If you use intel IG, you shouldnt have nvidia driver installed, and vice versa. I'm doubtful this is your problem, but it helped me when my machine was acting up.

Comment: @Ridderhoff's point helped me. I had both intel and nvidia installed on my ubuntu 17.10  since i have both on my laptop. In my case, i switched from intel to nvidia drivers  ('sudo prime-select nvidia') and rebooted and gparted opened.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is there in Ubuntu 17.10. Solved it by running the following command:

```
xhost +local:
```

Comment: This also fixed it for me on Pop!_OS 18.04

Comment: It also worked for Ubuntu 18.04.5