# How to set display resolution permanent in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, display-resolution, xrandr, reset, unknown-device

Unknown Display in Ubuntu 16.04. Set Resolution using xrandr command but after restart display resolution in reset.

> > sudo cvt 1368 768 60

after this output will here

> > ***#1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
> >     Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync***

then

> > sudo xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
> >
> > sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1368x768_60.00

display will change that time but after restart/re-login the display is changed to default 1024x768(4:3) and show the error like

> ### could not apply the stored configuration for monitors

but i want 1368x768(16:9).

I'm using dell S2216H display and Intel Inbuilt HD Graphics.

Comment: i need this configuration permanent.

Comment: First of all you don't have to use sudo for working with xrandr. Secondly, please paste the output of `xrandr` without arguments in your question, so we can see what the system reports.

Comment: @WillemK There is no output after `xrandr` command.  After these command execution screen resolution is changed but after restart resolution will reset.

Comment: very strange. Xrandr should report something. if it returns nothing I think you should try another display driver.

Answer (score 2):

You can reconfigure xOrg. I did this by creating a file in my `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` Directory.

I made it using vim:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/5-monitor.conf
```

Here is an example of my file.

```
Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "Monitor0"
   Modeline "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
   Modeline "3840x2160_30.0" 297.00 3840 4016 4104 4400 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync
   Modeline "4096x2160_24.0" 297.00 4096 5116 5204 5500 2160 2168 2178 2250 +hsync +vsync
EndSection
Section "Device"
   Identifier "Device0"
   Driver "intel"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
   Identifier "Screen0"
   Device "Device0"
   Monitor "Monitor0"
   DefaultDepth 24
   SubSection "Display"
      Depth 24
      Modes "3840x2160" "1920x1080"
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

For directions on how to do this you can follow this tutorial: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xorg/Multiple_monitors

I ran into this issue a little while back.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the output of `xrandr` could look like (I have shortened the list):

```
willem@TP420XU1604:~$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1600x900      60.01*+  40.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   .
   .
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
willem@TP420XU1604:~$
```

As I said in my comment, if you have no output at all, I think you have an issue with your graphics driver. Use `lshw -c video` to get info from the system. Please use the following post to troubleshoot: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system`