# Ubuntu 16.04 Stuck in Login Loop After Installing Cuda or Nvidia Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login, cuda

I wanted to install CUDA from Nvidia official website in ubuntu. After I installed it. Ubuntu became stuck in the Login session.

I searched this error in google, and many people have the same issue as me.

For now, I have tried those ways. But none of them worked.

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

[Ubuntu 16 Stuck in Login Loop after Installing Nvidia 364 Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers)

[After Upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 login screen runs in a loop while console login works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759995/after-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-login-screen-runs-in-a-loop-while-console-logi)

[Ubuntu 16 Stuck in Login Loop after Installing Nvidia 364 Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers)

[14.04 login loop after cuda installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632625/14-04-login-loop-after-cuda-installation)

I know it is caused by Nvidia graphic driver. But I tried all these methods, none of it worked for me.

By the way, My computer has two Graphic cards. One is Intel HD Graphics 530 and the another one is NVIDIA GTX 960M.

Thank you! I really need help!

Comment: remove cuda and reboot

Comment: Try looking at the following. [GUI Login Stuck in Loop after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927484/gui-login-stuck-in-loop-after-update)

Comment: By install do you mean like shown here & if so did you meet the requirements inc. using a supported kernel, ect. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html