# Lubuntu won't boot after installation

Tags: 16.04, boot, lubuntu

Before you close this thread as duplicate. I've read everything about this topic but nothing seems to work for me.

I recently dual booted Lubuntu 16.04 along side with Windows 7 32 bit. After reboot I see the GRUB menu and I click on Ubuntu, then it shows:

```
dev/sda5 clean, xxxx/xxxx files, xxxx/xxxxx blocks
```

It stops there.

If I do a hard reboot. It might pass this stage but still gets stuck in a black screen with only a command prompt.

I've read that I should open the terminal but pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> does nothing.

If I go through recovery it boots but gets stuck in a login loop.

Ive also tried `nomodeset` still nothing.

Comment: The message you posted is only a fsck (file system check) message which is done if it detects it wasn't shutdown correctly, or after x numbered boots. Are you sure you didn't install a server version?  Were you able to login? (you stated you get a command prompt).  What is the command prompt you get?

Comment: I'm just installing it for the first time and no it's not a server version. I can't login. The screen flashes every time I try to login. There's no command just an empty prompt (_) underscore.

Comment: I'd try ctrl+alt+f4 realizing you've already said you tried f1-f12 to see if you can get a prompt (ie. login window).  the "_" is more likely a cursor and not a prompt (a prompt means its waiting for command or input). If you can't login, I'd reboot (ctrl-alt-del if possible, ie. soft-boot) and edit your grub entry for lubuntu (hit <e> instead of <enter>).  then remove the 'quiet splash' from the linux line) and let it run. The quiet tells it to not display boot info, Splash tells it to display graphics - when you have issues you need all messages for diagnostics... This may reveal more.

Comment: I tried a removing quiet and splash. And pressed f10. It showed multiple logs and ended with the same cursor that's not blinking

Comment: Also now if I put nomodeset I get a white screen with characters I don't understand. E.g

Comment: the 'logs' are messages are what may contain the clue.  are they readable or did the screen `reset` (ie. blank) before you see the non-blinking cursor?  What you are describing anyway is most likely an issue with your video driver (**not** my strong suit). The messages ideally should be cut/pasted into your question (due limited formatting in comments), but put a link to photo if too-complicated. The last few lines are probably most important. Alternatively hit <e> (edit) on grub again, remove 'quiet splash' & add a ' 1 ' (or single).  It'll disable gui and hopefully give you a login prompt.

Comment: I think it's video driver issues. I've tried adding a '1' but this time it shows a blank screen. I can't get the messages it's moving too fast. but after the messages, it shows `login marvinkome: _` and then goes out and shows the non-blinking cursor. is it possible to update the drivers from my windows boot?

Comment: The [boot] messages are numerous, but your description now fits a fully 'up' system (ready to go) but with a dead video.  If you'd enabled `openssh-server` I suspect you'd be able to login from another machine, and explore/fix it, alas you're out of luck. Windoze can't mount a ext4 partition by default so nah. To explore I'd suggest using your Ubuntu install-media (boot and click 'try ubuntu'). You need to find what hardware you've actually got, and then mount your hdd & find what your install enabled and make changes needed.

Comment: This may contain a few clues https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system  but it contains some old info in some places (eg. I  saw mention of fglrx drivers which work in Ubuntu 14.04, but are no longer supported for 16.04 and later so use only if on 14.04). Regardless it contains info of finding what hardware you have, and what should be needed.

Comment: My Lubuntu installation doesn't have a try option it just starts with the select language. And also i tried changing the graphics with `vga=xxx` in grup it now loads past the disk check but stops in `marvinkome login: _` then the screen updates and shows a non-blinking cursor without me typing anything.