# Screen goes black after waking from suspend on Lubuntu 21.04

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, brightness

The screen of my laptop goes black when it wakes up from suspend. I don't think that the laptop freezes because I can do REISUB. I suppose it's a problem with the brightness, but I could be wrong.

Some of the things I've tried include turning up the brightness via the corresponding shortcuts, booting using `nomodeset`, pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> shortcuts, and uninstalling Redshift. But, none of them did anything.

I guess I could try going into TTY, but I don't know what I'd enter.

A few things that might be worth noting is that I have Redshift installed and I'm on Lubuntu 21.04.

Regarding my graphics card and drivers, I hope that the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3` [1] provides enough information:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 500 [8086:5a85] (rev 0b)
        DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 500 [8086:2212]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Any ideas?

---

[1] BuZZ-dEE, “You can use the command `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep ’in us` to see what video driver is in use on your system.,” Ask Ubuntu, Feb. 14, 2013. [How can I find what video driver is in use on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system) (accessed Jun. 03, 2021).

Comment: Graphics card and drivers?

Comment: I updated the post to provide information about that. Let me know if it fulfills your request. @ChanganAuto

Comment: It does, thank you and +1. Unfortunately it rules out my original hypotheses of it being related with Nvidia and incorrect drivers.

Comment: Do any other possible reasons for my issue come to your mind? @ChanganAuto

Comment: Sorry no, not really. Update UEFI just in case.

Comment: It's ok. I'll try doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried switching to text terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 for example) then back to GUI.. I've had that help, though if it doesn't I tend to explore using the terminal & resolve the issue with a `kill`.   On wake, the screen should be locked by `xscreensaver` that may require you to hit a key to wake it (so it asks for a password).

Comment: Yes, I've tried going into text terminal, then back to GUI, but I got nothing. I'll try the other thing you said. @guiverc

Comment: Hey, sorry to trouble you. I'm having a hard time finding anything on updating BIOS/UEFI. I understand that I'm supposed to read the documentation of the vendor of my BIOS/UEFI. The vendor of my BIOS/UEFI seems to be American Megatrends. However, their website doesn't seem to have anything on updating BIOS/UEFI. There are a handful of online articles on how to do this, but I'm skeptical about them. Could you give me some pointers on how to find reliable information? @ChanganAuto

Comment: You should find the latest version at the laptop's manufacturer, not the generic firmware provider, along with all other drivers and additional software.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much! I'll give that a shot. @ChanganAuto