# Connect Dell XPS-15 with Ubuntu 18.04 to Samsung 6 Series TV with HDMI

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, samsung, smart-tv

I am trying to use my Samsung 6 Series TV as a secondary monitor for Dell XPS-15 laptop using an HDMI cable. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

What I am encountering is that on my laptop, the second display is detected, I can go into the Displays tab under Devices in the Settings and see that a Samsung Electric Company 85" is detected.

On the display of the Samsung TV however, I see that there is No Signal.

When I have connect instead to an LG TV, or a Dell monitor, I have encountered no problems.

I have tried using the Samsung TV as a second display with this same laptop, but on my Windows partition (I am dual-booting), and I have encountered no problems with using the Samsung TV as a second display, which leads me to think that there must be something I can do to get this setup to work with Ubuntu as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

More information:

If I run the command `lshw -c video`, I get the following output:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:180 memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:178 memory:eb000000-ebffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

If I run the command `modinfo $(modprobe --resolve-alias nvidia)`, this gives me:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-81-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        460.91.03
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA
srcversion:     EA32CEBBA576FA0CDF3786B
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc02i00*
alias:          pci:v000010DEd*sv*sd*bc03sc00i00*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           nvidia
vermagic:       5.4.0-81-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           NvSwitchRegDwords:NvSwitch regkey (charp)
parm:           NvSwitchBlacklist:NvSwitchBlacklist=uuid[,uuid...] (charp)
parm:           nv_cap_enable_devfs:Enable (1) or disable (0) nv-caps devfs support. Default: 1 (int)
parm:           NVreg_ResmanDebugLevel:int
parm:           NVreg_RmLogonRC:int
parm:           NVreg_ModifyDeviceFiles:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileUID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileGID:int
parm:           NVreg_DeviceFileMode:int
parm:           NVreg_InitializeSystemMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_UsePageAttributeTable:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterForACPIEvents:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIeGen3:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableMSI:int
parm:           NVreg_TCEBypassMode:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableStreamMemOPs:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler:int
parm:           NVreg_RestrictProfilingToAdminUsers:int
parm:           NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableS0ixPowerManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_S0ixPowerManagementVideoMemoryThreshold:int
parm:           NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_DynamicPowerManagementVideoMemoryThreshold:int
parm:           NVreg_EnableUserNUMAManagement:int
parm:           NVreg_MemoryPoolSize:int
parm:           NVreg_KMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_VMallocHeapMaxSize:int
parm:           NVreg_IgnoreMMIOCheck:int
parm:           NVreg_NvLinkDisable:int
parm:           NVreg_EnablePCIERelaxedOrderingMode:int
parm:           NVreg_RegisterPCIDriver:int
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwords:charp
parm:           NVreg_RegistryDwordsPerDevice:charp
parm:           NVreg_RmMsg:charp
parm:           NVreg_GpuBlacklist:charp
parm:           NVreg_TemporaryFilePath:charp
```

Finally, if I run the command `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`, I obtain:

`Kernel driver in use: i915`.

These commands I found on the askubuntu page: [How can I find what video driver is in use on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system)

Thanks again!

Comment: Open Nvidia X Server settings and choose the high performance profile, the one that enables the Nvidia card instead of the default integrated Intel. REBOOT. Any change?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on the Samsung end.
Under

> Settings → General → External Device Manager

one can turn on the *HDMI UHD Color Setting* for the HDMI port you are connected to. Once this was turned on, the display from my laptop immediately appeared. Problem Solved!