# Most of UI freezing when crossing mouse between four monitor corner

Tags: freeze, amd-graphics, wayland

Alright so I've got a weird one.

I have 6 monitors arranged in a 3x2. When I cross my cursor near where the 4 right-most monitors meet, *most* of the UI freezes. Terminals keep doing what they're doing, but everything else freezes, like the time or Firefox. Also if I let it sit like this, eventually the desktop fades and locks. Sound keeps playing from Spotify, but it looks frozen. I thought this was random, but I can actually get it to repeat if I move my mouse around that corner.

No inputs work whatsoever. I can't switch between virtual terminals with Ctrl+Alt+F4, and I can't kill programs with Alt+F4, or by moving the mouse to where I know there to be close window buttons and clicking (can still hear the programs playing audio).

I've done a complete hardware swap. ASUS -> Gigabyte motherboard, different memory, new M.2 drive, new GPU, new CPU. My original setup was also 20.04 but my new install on my new drive is 22.04 and it has exactly the same issue. But I've never seen this before so it must have been some kind of update very recently because I use this computer every day and it just started about a week ago, I just don't know for what. Also, 20.04 was Xorg, and 22.04 is using Wayland.

6 monitors are being driven by a single GPU: [Radeon HD 7750 2GB GDDR5 6M (6x MiniDP)](https://www.visiontek.com/products/radeon-7750-2gb-gddr5-6m-6x-minidp). Only default drivers are being used, this is basically just a fresh install of Ubuntu that is up to date. Both bioses on both motherboards were also up to date, and this was with two different of the same GPU. I thought it was originally hardware, but now that I can repeat it I'm pretty sure it's a software bug.

If there's any other info I can give please let me know, since this freezing is super frustrating.

---

Output from `inxi -G`

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Cape Verde PRO [Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E] driver: radeon
    v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.0 driver: X: loaded: radeon
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: radeon resolution:
    1: 1920x1200~60Hz 2: 1920x1200~60Hz 3: 1920x1200~60Hz 4: 1920x1200~60Hz
    5: 1920x1200~60Hz 6: 1920x1200~60Hz
  Message: Wayland GBM/EGL data currently not available.
```

Comment: Add the output of `inxi -G`. Did you try `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`? Using fractional scaling? Seems a bug (out of AU scope). Would be nice to look `htop` output on the freezing moments, maybe from another host through ssh. That way, you could find which process is the culprit. Then you could `strace`/`ptrace` to go deeper on what's happening.

Comment: Mmm good suggestion with the ssh I didn't even think of that. I have not done `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` though, no. Just running it now simply prints `All the available drivers are already installed.` Added the `inxi -G` output.

Comment: You could also try if it happens in X11 and take a look to logs, `journalctrl -xe`

Comment: Was able to trigger it with the other 4 monitor junction. SSH'ed in, htop shows `gnome-shell` pegged at 100. Nothing in the journal. Killing it just logged me out and it works without restarting, but all my things are closed, so essentially the same result.

Comment: Maybe [this bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/4159)? [It seems](https://askubuntu.com/a/254877/349837) you are using the [open source Radeon driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver). Try a live distro, disconnecting some monitors... Either way, seems a bug, file a bug report on gnome-shell GitLab. The output of [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org) might be useful.

Comment: I have similar problem with only one external monitor (and the laptop monitor, two in total). I had enabled fractional scaling to get better control, but resizing windows on external monitor freezes gnome. Disabling fractional scaling solved it for me for now. HP ZBook Fury i9, 64G mem, Nvidia graphics.