# 3rd Screen Support Issue

Tags: display, display-rotation

I am running *Ubuntu 22.0.4.1 LTS x86_64* with 3 logically attached screens, as follows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5600 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected 1080x1920+4520+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 3440x1440+1080+480 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 335mm
   3440x1440     59.97*+  74.98    29.99  
   2560x1080     59.98    59.94    50.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1720x1440     59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 1080x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93
```

For drivers,I am running the latest tested version of NVIDIA, as follows:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU104 [GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:149 memory:53000000-53ffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff memory:50000000-51ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 4
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768
```

Upon boot, I am presented with 2 *always* but the `HDMI-0` screen does not work without being messed with. Sometimes it's as simple as moving the orientation in the "Settings -- Display", or sometimes this command works:

```
sleep 5 && xrandr -d :1 --output HDMI-0 --auto
```

The third screen is always registered in NVIDIA Control, `xrandr` and Settings, but just not on ("black screen"). Looking for logs, I cannot locate an error (`/var/log/syslog`) as follows:

```
Aug 29 06:48:56 therion /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3560]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-4: nvidia-auto-select @1080x1920 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1080x1920, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, Rotation=90}, DP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1080x1920 +4520+0 {ViewPortIn=1080x1920, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, Rotation=270}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @3440x1440 +1080+480 {ViewPortIn=3440x1440, ViewPortOut=3440x1440+0+0}"
```

Lastly, `dmesg` only resolves a few errors, such as:

```
[48033.822745] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to grab modeset ownership
```

(HOwever at this time, the screen *was* working)

What logs, or process can I start using to diagnose why one screen occasionally doesn't work? I have noted going to sleep and unlocking will also sometimes resolve my issue.

Comment: `lspci -nnk | egrep -i --color 'vga|3d|2d' -A3 | grep 'in use'` confirmed - reviewed [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system)

Comment: Is it possible that your GPU does not support 3 simultaneous outputs? My GPU has 3 outputs, but it only supports 2 at the same time. For the 3rd monitor, I have to use a second GPU on my second PCIEx4 port.

Comment: @EmreTalha - no, the third screen *does* eventually work.