# Is this the right way to install Radeon RX 6800XT drivers?

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I'm RTFM [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/amdgpu-installation). They say to download the `tar` archive, but the [link](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers) provided leads to a `deb` package. Anyway, I was pretty sure my board should support the pro version of amdgpu driver, but I can only see the open version [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-6000-series/amd-radeon-6800-series/amd-radeon-rx-6800-xt).

Anyway I downloaded the deb package and installed it. Now I have the `amdgpu-install` command (NOT pro). But still I can install the Vulkan drivers, which seems not possible from the first link (they should be only in the pro variant). I'm quite confused.

I installed all the stuff using:

```
amdgpu-install --opencl=rocr --opengl=mesa --vulkan=pro --usecase=graphics,opencl --accept-eula
```

It completed the installation and I can see stuff under `/opt`:

```
$ ls /opt/
rocm  rocm-5.4.3
```

And here some other outputs:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 21 [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:f80-f7f iomemory:fc0-fbf irq:201 memory:f800000000-fbffffffff memory:fc00000000-fc0fffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fca00000-fcafffff memory:fcb00000-fcb1ffff
```

```
$ modinfo amdgpu 
filename:       /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    AMD GPU
author:         AMD linux driver team
...

$ dpkg -l | grep amdgpu
ii  amdgpu-install                             5.4.50403-1538762.20.04                   all          AMDGPU driver repository and installer
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                       2.4.113-2                                 amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                  22.0.0-3                                  amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver

$ dpkg -l | grep vulkan
ii  libvulkan1:amd64                           1.3.224.0-1                               amd64        Vulkan loader library
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64                  22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1                         amd64        Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers

$ dpkg -l | grep rocr
ii  hsa-rocr                                   1.7.0.50403-121~22.04                     amd64        AMD Heterogeneous System Architecture HSA - Linux HSA Runtime for Boltzmann (ROCm) platforms

$ dpkg -l | grep mesa
ii  libegl-mesa0:amd64                         22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1                         amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- Mesa vendor library
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                      22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1                         amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
rc  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                       22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1                         i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                        22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1                         amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                         9.0.2-1                                   amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglx-mesa0:amd64                         22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1                         amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX vendor library
ii  mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64                  22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1                         amd64        Mesa Vulkan graphics drivers
```

Still I'm not sure if I have the drivers installed and running.
For example I have no `vulkaninfo` command and Blender does not enable the cycle renderer because it does not find a suitable GPU.

What else should I do in order to enable my graphic card?
I'm running Ubuntu 22.10

### UPDATE

After seeing the comments, some more clarifications:

- I tried to install the drivers by myself following the official documentations. Usually, questions that does NOT report this will be downvoted or closed. I showed my effort. I strongly hope this would be appreciated.
- I'm not asking for an opinion! I'm kindly asking to check what I did and help me to understand if I did it correctly or not
- if what I did is not the right way to install the drivers, please tell me what procedure I need to follow since I tried to read the manufacturer manual

Comment: What driver did you install for the graphics card? What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: So, you've followed a howto by AMD, and now ask for opinions? I hope it is the right way, but amdgpu is also preinstalled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)

Comment: @David the driver version is reported in the outputs I guess. Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: @mikewhatever of course, before posting I try by myself. Otherwise my question will be closed because I did not my homework. And I'm not asking for an "opinion". I kindly asked to inspect what I did and correct me if I did it wrong.

Comment: @karel sorry, it doesn't fit for me. It's very outdated and I'm confused about all the options the answers suggest. I'm just looking for the right way to install the drivers for the GPU (if I did it wrong) or how to checkout if they are installed correctly, looking at the command I gave.

Comment: Who told you it was outdated? Probably some stupid old blog. Drivers for AMD graphics processors are preinstalled in Ubuntu by default, so Ubuntu  users don't need to guess which graphics drivers to install.

Comment: @karel the question you linked talks about Ubuntu 14/16, while I'm trying to install drivers on Ubuntu 22.10. Anyway, if the drivers are pre-installed, why Blender cannot find a GPU to enable cycles?

Comment: @karel in other words, how to be sure I'm actually using the GPU and not the CPU only?

Comment: [How can I find what video driver is in use on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/q/23238/)

Comment: @karel did you read my question? I've already reported the output of the command in your link

Comment: You think we didn't tell you what to do, but we did. Don't keep trying trying to install graphics drivers that you don't need to install. Ubuntu has has been like this for nine years since Ubuntu 14.04 trusty.

Comment: @karel ok, but can you please explain why I can't use my GPU in blender then?

Comment: [Blender 3.0’s Cycles X now runs on AMD GPUs](https://www.cgchannel.com/2021/11/cycles-x-now-runs-on-amd-gpus/) then scroll down to where it says "Which AMD GPUs will Cycles X run on?"

Comment: @karel so my 6800 should be supported...

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky but I can actually answer the preceding comment so I will. I'm a macOS user on my other desktop computer and I've installed a lot of open source software in macOS through homebrew. It always installs perfectly and about half the time the software doesn't work after installing it. Lesson learned - don't absolutely trust software from non-official (i.e. non-Ubuntu official) repositories. There's a 50/50 chance that it won't work.

Comment: @karel, ok I removed and purged the official AMD drivers, so I'm running again the default Ubuntu drivers. But the behavior is not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, my procedure was incomplete. To correctly install the drivers I had to invoke the installer with the `-y` argument after selecting the packages as per the original question.

So, after:

```
amdgpu-install --opencl=rocr --opengl=mesa --vulkan=pro --usecase=graphics,opencl --accept-eula
```

I also issued:

```
amdgpu-install -y
```

This did the trick and now Blender can see my GPU card.
I didn't understand this step from the docs, but I found the hint [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/283104/96843).

I did the procedure a couple of times: without the newer drivers from the AMD site, the GPU does not work properly.