# Multi screen not working on Ubuntu 22.04 on Lenovo laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo, intel-graphics, intel

I have a dual operating system  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and Window 11, on window 11 the external two screen works fine while on Ubuntu it does not and I can't see any configuration in the setting.
The below are details from the command line.

```
$ lshw -c video
 *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6002000000-6002ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 4
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080
```

From this command `modinfo i915` as per this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system).
I can't see the configuration any more after I followed the below link
[Intel](https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/driver/installation.html).

I followed also this [link](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/install-intel-graphic-drivers)
Nothing happened
The below from the settings
Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)
processor: Intel® Pentium(R) Gold 7505 @ 2.00GHz × 4

Also the ThinkPad laptop for my colleague works out of the box for external multimonitor on Ubuntu 22.04.